# C++/OpenGL VAO Problems

Tags: c++, function, opengl, vbo, vao

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600
#define TITLE "Dynamic"

GLFWwindow* window;
int vaoID;

float vertices[] = {-0.5f, 0.5f, 0, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0,    0.5f, 0.5f, 0,  0.5f, 0.5f, 0,  -0.5f, -0.5f,   0,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0};

void loadToVAO(float vertices[]);

void update() {
    loadToVAO(vertices);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit())
        std::cout << "Couldn't initialize GLFW!" << std::endl;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE, NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit())
        std::cout << "GLEW fucked up!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Your GL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    update();
}



void loadShaders() {

}

void loadToVAO(float vertices[]) {
    GLuint vboID;
    GLuint vaoID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices) * 8, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    std::cout << vaoID << std::endl;
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

This is my code for creating and rendering a VAO that contains a VBO with the vertex positions. But unfortunately it doesn't work. It draws a triangle instead of a quad. But when I put the code of the loadToVAO function in the update function before the while loop, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator always returns the size of the underlying type. When you copy the content of `loadToVAO` to the update function, `sizeof(vertices)` is basically `sizeof(float[18])`, which is the total size of the array.

But inside the `loadToVAO`, the `sizeof(vertices)` takes the function parameter `vertices` as input and not the global variable. Since array parameters of undefined size in C++ are treated as points of the same type we have here:

```
sizeof(vertices) == sizeof(float[]) == sizeof(float*)
```

which is the size of a pointer (4 or 8) and not the size of the data anymore.

To solve this, you can either pass the size of the array also to the function, which is the C way to go. The more modern way is to use `std::array` or `std::vector` to store the data in the first place.

Edit: On the second look I saw that you used `sizeof(vertices) * 8` in the first place. I'm not really sure where the 8 comes from, since you neither have 8 elements nor does a float have a size of 8 bytes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is now working. The 8 has to do with the byte size

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer :)